# The UPDATE statement adds blank to the other rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running an UPDATE statement on PHP using PDO.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" class="form-style">

    <h3>ACTUALIZAR PRODUCTOS</h3>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label>Codigo del producto a actualizar:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" />

        <label>Nombre producto:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />

        <label>Marca:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marca" />

        <label>Descripcion:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="desc"></textarea>

    </div>                              
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="actualizar">Actualizar Producto</button>
</form>
```

And here is the code:

```
<?php

$errores = array();
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$marca = $_POST['marca'];
$descripcion = $_POST['desc'];
$codigo = $_POST['code'];

if(isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {

        if(empty($nombre)) {
            $nombre = null;
        }

        if(empty($marca)) {
            $marca = null;
        }

        if(empty($descripcion)) {
            $descripcion = null;
        }

        if(empty($codigo)) {
            $codigo = null;
        }


        $sentencia = $conn_db->prepare("UPDATE productos SET nombre = :nombre, marca = :marca, descripcion = :descripcion WHERE codigo = :codigo");
        $sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':marca', $marca, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':descripcion', $descripcion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia -> execute();

        echo "Producto actualizado con exito.";
        exit();

} 
?>
```

The problem is that whenever I want to change only 1 row from the product, it adds blank to the others rows. For example, I want to update only the "Name" of the product, I write the new name on the form and when I hit submit, the name is changed in the DB but also the other rows are set to blank.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Still learning PHP. Thanks.

Comment: You're always updating everything, whether there's something to be changed or not. Instead of always binding all the parameters, check and see if there's something to change, and only include the updated fields.

Comment: then dont use that prepared statement, you should create one only depending of what you need to update, if you send blank parameters to the rest of columns, it will update them like that...

Comment: But what if I want to change for example, the name, the brand and the description of the product? I must do one statement for each row?

Comment: @TarkyKrocky - no. You can do one statement, with three parameters in it. You just need to create the statement differently, depending on what needs updating. If `product_name` needs to change, then include it in your statement, and pass in the value when you execute it; if it doesn't need to change, than omit it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing so is to populate form fields with existing data. This would make your action actual *editing* as one will be able to to fix one letter in the description instead of writing it over from scratch.

So, before showing your form, select the corresponding row from database, and fill `value` attributes with the actual values (don't forget to process them all with `htmlspecialchars()` first).

This way on submit everything will be updated all right.